# Matching pandas dataframe rows in a spreadsheet with Xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlwings

I am writing a script to:

- import spreadsheets as pandas dataframes
- export, sort and compile them in a single XL spreadsheet via Xlwings

My issue is that the inputs do not have the exact same number and values of indexes. I am trying to ensure that every row would be matching to show the right values in the right rows for all dataframes in my final spreadsheet, and that rows that only exist in one dataframe would be completed by zero values in the others.

As an exemple, i have set together the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
```

```
df1= pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('test2.xlsx')
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

```
  Header 1 Header 2  Header 3
0     Cat1        A       150
1     Cat1        A       200
2     Cat1        A       250
3     Cat2        A       300
4     Cat3        B       300
5     Cat3        B       350
6     Cat3        C         0
7     Cat4        C         0
8     Cat5        D        50
   Header 1 Header 2  Header 3
0      Cat1        A       150
1      Cat1        A       200
2      Cat1        A       250
3      Cat1        A       350
4      Cat2        A       300
5      Cat3        B       300
6      Cat3        B       350
7      Cat3        C         0
8      Cat5        D        50
9      Cat6        A       250
10     Cat6        B       250
```

```
sht=xw.Book().sheets[0]
sht.range('A1').value = df1
sht.range('E1').value = df2
```

In the end the result does not match all  Cat 1 / A / numbers on the same row etc.

Any idea?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I honestly did not understand your issue, may you check and revise it ? It sounds nonsense to me.

> My issue is that the inputs do not have the exact same number and values of indexes. I am trying to ensure that every row would be matching to show the right values in the right rows for all dataframes in my final spreadsheet, and that rows that only exist in one dataframe would be completed by zero values in the others.

However, I can help you with your two first requests, for both I would use `xlwings` indeed:

for both, use `import xlwings as xw`

***1) import spreadsheets as pandas dataframes***

`df = pd.DataFrame(xw.Book(file_path).sheets['SheetName'].range((1,1), (10, 3)).value)`

This will create a Pandas.Dataframe object with values found in your excel file, in the sheet 'SheetName' from A1 to C10 . Be aware Excel (and xlwings) ha 1-based index, not 0-based, hence first row is 1 , first column is 1 - in "normal" Python, the first would be 0.

***2) export, sort and compile them in a single XL spreadsheet via Xlwings***
Your code is quite correct here, general API call would be:

`xw.Book(file_path).sheets['SheetName'].range('A1')= df`

Make your request more clear so you can get more help.